# What is alternative for angular.forEach in angular 7

Tags: angular7

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBY2H.png

```
getChartData = function(d,i,isBarChart=false){
   var cData = []; 
   angular.forEach(d, function(value, key) {
    cData.push({"key": value.key,"value": value.values[i].y});
   });
   //console.log(cData);
   return (isBarChart ? this.toBarChart(cData) : cData); 
 };
```

Comment: There are a bunch of alternatives using Vanilla JavaScript and they are not framework specific. Do let me know if you are okay with me listing those methods instead.

Comment: Iterating through objects: https://hackernoon.com/5-techniques-to-iterate-over-javascript-object-entries-and-their-performance-6602dcb708a8

Comment: Iterating through arrays: https://codeburst.io/javascript-map-vs-foreach-f38111822c0f

Answer (score 0):

You can use the methods available in javascript. A list of the methods that may be useful for your scenario:

`Array.forEach()`,
`Array.map()`, `Object.keys(object)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple `javascript forEach` method:

**Example:**

```
let myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];

myArray.forEach((item) => {
   console.log(item);
});
```

Your updated code:

```
getChartData = function(d,i,isBarChart=false){
  var cData = [];
     d.forEach(function(value, key) {
      cData.push({"key": value.key,"value": value.values[i].y});
    });
    //console.log(cData);  
   return (isBarChart ? this.toBarChart(cData) : cData);
};
```